# Review queues missing

Tags: support, status-bydesign, review

I am active mainly in two sites: main SO and Russian.SE - including performing reviews.  Normally, when I click the `review` link, I expect to see 6 queues: close votes, reopen votes, suggested edits, first posts, late answers and low quality posts.  They may appear in different order based on what's available and which ones I exhausted for the day.  On the main SO site there are always 6 queues.  On the other, on Russian.SE sometimes I see all 6 queues (possibly with 0 questions in all of them), but sometimes some of the queues are missing.  Below is the screenshot from this morning, where only three of the six queues are available.  As that site is still in beta and doesn't have a lot of activity, most likely, the missing queues have 0 questions, but then the ones showing also have 0 questions, so I'm a bit confused as to what's happening here.

**EDIT** I believe I got to the bottom of it now.  Apparently, the screenshot is of the review for meta.russian.SE - which has 3 queues.  Once I went back to main russian.SE and into review there, all 6 queues were available again.

[image]

Comment: Looks like all Meta sites (not related to Beta) now have only 3 queues, except this one that got four. I'd say by design, let's wait for some official confirmation though. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd You should actually put that as the answer, as this is exactly what got me on the right track!  Somehow I didn't notice that I was looking at the review for meta.russian.se as opposed to russian.se.  I think this is the main difference.  Once I got to the russian.se review, all 6 queues are there.

Comment: Still not sure that's how it always was, better have a dev come and explain. What you think?

Answer (score 7):

Not all queues are active on all sites, because there isn't a need for them (yet). Stack Overflow is a very busy site, so only there the extra help is needed.

Here on Meta, for example, we 'only' have 4 of the queues, low quality, suggested edits, reopen and close.

I suspect, but I am not certain, that the developers are still tuning what queues need to show up where, and that's why you have seen more queues before.

In other words, this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), not a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). :-)

Comment: That doesn't explain why the OP is seeing different queues intermittently?

Comment: @Rory: tuning, I suspect, updated the answer.

Comment: I second @Rory's comment.  If I were always seeing these three queues, that would be understandable, however sometimes I do see all six.  Specifically, "first posts" queue is a very reasonable expectation for a young site, with new members joining in.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't have enough reputation on meta to access the review queues, so can't compare.

Comment: @AleksG: You'll have to wait for a dev to speak up about this then; it could be that the choice of available queues is automated and then there'd be a bug. I however *strongly* suspect that either the devs or the moderators have a switch for these and that it's being toggled manually a few times.

Comment: Yup, this is the case.

Comment: @Nick so Meta sites always had only 3 queues, or is this something new?