# Help centre refers to review queues, a privilege, and a link that do not exist

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, privileges, help-center

The help centre for MSO states (on this page: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues):

> "The first queues you gain access to are Late Answers and First Posts. These and all other review queues are accessible from the "review" link that appears at the top of every page next to your user name."

At the top of this and most pages next to my user name I see only rep, badge count, "chat", "main", "about", "help", and a search bar, so to me that quote just looks *wrong* (and not very helpful).

I originally wrote up a question asking about how to get access to those review queues, and why I could not find the link, since I spent so long looking for them, but I was able to get to a page with list of 4 other review queues (through a link in the help centre), and I imagined there is only one review queue list page, so something strange must be going on.

Finally, before posting that question I came across a question ([Review queues missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153664/review-queues-missing)) with critical information I did not see anywhere else in my hunt for the link and for the review cues I supposedly now had access to:

> Here on Meta, for example, we 'only' have 4 of the queues, low
>   quality, suggested edits, reopen and close.

If this *is* true, it makes sense that I would not see a review link (as I do not have enough rep for any of the review queues that do exist), but can we please change the Meta help centre so that it stops referring to

- queues that do not exist
- a privilege that does not exist
- a link that does not exist

?

A lot of confusion could be avoided if the related privilege were removed from the list (and its help page were removed as well).

---

Update:

I see some of the reasons given for the current unfortunate set-up on another question ([MSO Review Queue Privileges are Misleading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191516/mso-review-queue-privileges-are-misleading)):

1. MSO has a "master privilege list" for all sites, so it can't be changed.
2. MSO users with at least 500 rep do technically have access to the first posts and late answers queue...it's just that it does not exist.

"1." is apparently not true, as WendiKidd points out in the comments there.  Privilege lists *are* changed in new SE sites to allow for lower rep thresholds.

"2." is just very unintuitive (and cost me and potentially others much time sussing out the answer to how it all works).

If we *still* don't want to or can't fix things as I suggest above, though, I suggest we:

- Start showing the "review" link on MSO starting at 500 rep regardless (as long as the help centre is saying it is there).
- On the review queue page, show placeholder messages for review queues that do not exist *mentioning* that they do not exist (so people do not think they are on a separate page somewhere).